# Create a redirect link using data from a text file

Tags: java, php, html

I have a few servers running on my home network. This network has a dynamic IP address that changes a good bit. Which means if i want to access my network from somewhere else i need the IP. This i've solved with a java program i wrote to get the public IP. Which works just fine but is a bit of a pain to grab it from a text file in my dropbox each time it changes.

What i'm looking to do is create a web page to redirect me to my network using the IP. The issue is i don't really have the knowledge to do it. As well google hasn't exactly got me any closer to figuring it out. Now i am a programmer so i can understand the code but have no web coding knowledge so i don't know were to start on figuring this out. So any help would be nice, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need Dynamic DNS more than a program. Dynamic DNS will follow your IP whenever it changes so you can link it to a domain name.

A second option is to set up your own DNS server (offsite) and have your script feed the IP into that DNS server. Keep the Time To Live(TTL) low (like 1 min) and you can move your IP as often as you like.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you ought to be doing is using dynamic dns.